# Changing post url for the application in jQuery

Tags: jquery, grails, web

I have some jQuery code that looks like this:

```
$.post("/myapp/mycontroller/save", { myObject: JSON.stringify(jsonObject) })
    .done(function(data) {
        $("#successmsg").text(data);
        $("#successmsg").show();
    });
```

This all works fine on my local environment because name of my app when running on local environment is `myapp`

However, when I deploy to test environment, the name of the app is `mytestapp` so this code fails to work on test environment.

How do I resolve this problem? How can I simply take out the app name?

Comment: Being honest, you could use an alias

Answer (score 0):

Use url parsing

```
var context = window.location.href.split('/')[3]
$.post("/"+context+"/mycontroller/save", ...
```

I work in a rails shop and this is a regular problem. This solves it every time, and gets used on every project.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your html:

```
<script>
$(function() {
     var baseUrl = //YourDynamicallyGeneratedBaseURL;
});
</script>
```

and the Ajax call would be like:

```
$.post(baseUrl + "/mycontroller/save", ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Element/base) element with a base URL for all your relative URLs.

```
<base href="/myapp/">
```

This way you can control the base URL for production and development environments differently.

For example, your AJAX URL will become:

```
$.post("mycontroller/save", {
  ...
});
```

Comment: so i'll have to change this everytime I deploy the application?

Comment: @birdy, that is if you lack a proper environment configuration

Answer (score 0):

Your server url should already be defined in your config (`grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` unless you have changed it):

```
grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/myapp"
```

Then in your layout (by default, the main layout is `grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp`)

```
<g:javascript>var baseURL = '${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}';</g:javascript>
```

Then `baseURL` can be accessed in any of your `.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid specifying base urls, unless you have to (Ajax call from another app).

If your call is from the same application, then your problem should be easily solved by doing the following :

```
$.post("${g.createLink(controller:'mycontroller', 
        action: 'save')}", 
        { myObject: JSON.stringify(jsonObject) })
    .done(function(data) {
        $("#successmsg").text(data);
        $("#successmsg").show();
    });
```